# How to update Wordpress files through git remote pushes if user doesn't own the directories?

Tags: wordpress, git, ubuntu, wordpress-theming

All Wordpress files and directories are owned by `www-data` user/group (`Apache`), directories are `755`, files are `644`. So, if I'm trying to `git push` something to the server using my ssh account, my user can't create any files, so I can't push anything.

The user is in `www-data` group, so changing Wordpress permissions to `775`/`664` looks like a solution, but it feels too permissive for the site's safety. I need a bit of advice.

Comment: How do you update files at the server-side? Do you use post-receive/post-update hooks?

Comment: I can use hooks, or just create a repo inside wordpress themes folder. Both methods are not working because of permissions.

Comment: The idea is - is there any better way to work with Wordpress themes using git, except providing 775/664 permissions to Wordpress files.

Comment: Inside hooks you can use passwordless `sudo` but that's even more permissive. Perhaps a better solutions is to login as the user `www-data` during push. `git push www-data@server`

Comment: `www-data` user is `no-login`, it's a web server, so yeah, permissions look like the best solution; thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hint: [`git config core.sharedRepository group`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+sharedrepository+group)